# R - how to apply output of ifelse(str_detect ...) to whole group

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to flag all instances in a group if one variable contains the values "PICU" or "CCCU" (or both).

```
    library(dplyr)

# construct sample tibble:
df <- tibble(
  key = rep(1:7, 3),
  Unit = rep(c('7A', '2B','CCCU', 'PICU'), length = 21))
```

I am using the following code, which only flags rows that contain these terms, but not the rest in that group.

```
icu <- qlik %>%
  select(key, Unit) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(ICU = ifelse(str_detect(Patient_Unit, 'PICU|CCCU') == 'TRUE', 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do

```
df %>% select(key, Unit) %>%
  group_by(key) %>% mutate(ICU = 1 * any(c("PICU", "CCCU") %in% Unit))
# A tibble: 21 x 3
# Groups:   key [7]
#      key Unit    ICU
#    <int> <chr> <dbl>
#  1     1 7A        1
#  2     2 2B        1
#  3     3 CCCU      1
#  4     4 PICU      1
#  5     5 7A        1
#  6     6 2B        1
#  7     7 CCCU      1
#  8     1 PICU      1
#  9     2 7A        1
# 10     3 2B        1
# ... with 11 more rows
```

So that the whole group of `ICU` will be 1 if `any` of `PICU` and `CCCU` is among the values of `Unit` in the corresponding group.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the outcome you're looking for?

```
> flag <- c('PICU', 'CCCU')
> df %>%
+   group_by(key) %>%
+     mutate(ICU = Patient_Unit %in% flag)

# A tibble: 21 x 3

# Groups:   key [7]
     key Patient_Unit ICU 
   <int> <chr>        <lgl>
 1     1 7A           FALSE
 2     2 2B           FALSE
 3     3 CCCU         TRUE 
 4     4 PICU         TRUE 
 5     5 7A           FALSE
 6     6 2B           FALSE
 7     7 CCCU         TRUE 
 8     1 PICU         TRUE 
 9     2 7A           FALSE
10     3 2B           FALSE
# ... with 11 more rows
```